# Okta Angular OpenID - auth guard preventing tokens from being consumed during callback

Tags: angular, authentication, redirect, okta, okta-api

I'm following this tutorial, which is a great one!  It shows how to use Okta for authentication.

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/04/17/angular-authentication-with-oidc

This tutorial has a `HomeComponent` that is assigned to the root route and has elements show or not show depending on whether or not a user is signed in.  So, in `app.component.ts`, you can capture the tokens to store in storage from the parts of the url with the following in your constructor:

```js
this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument().then(() => {
    this.oauthService.tryLogin({});
}
```

And in an `auth.guard.ts`, you could have:

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (this.oauthService.hasValidIdToken()) {
        return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    return false;
}
```

With this routing configuration:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'edit/:id', component: EditComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
];
```

### My Problem

I have a slightly different setup and the timing of everything is not working out right.
- I have a `LoginComponent` that you get redirected to if you are not authenticated.
- I redirect the root route to a `AuthGuard`ed route.
- `this.oauthService.tryLogin({})` is not run in time to beat the `AuthGuard` from redirecting me to the `LoginComponent` when I login with Okta.  This causes the url parts that include the tokens to persist in storage to go away before I try to consume them.

Here is what I have:

#### `app.component.ts`

```js
constructor(
    ...
    private oauthService: OAuthService) {
    ...
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument().then(() => {
      this.oauthService.tryLogin({});
    });
}
```

#### `auth.guard.ts`

```js
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
  if (!this.oauthService.hasValidIdToken()) {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
  return true;
}
```

#### `app-routing.module.ts`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/projects', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'help', component: HelpComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

#### `projects-routing.module.ts`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
{ 
  path: 'projects', 
  component: ProjectsComponent, 
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

As you can see, when I go to my Okta site to put in my username and password, I get redirected to the root of my application, the `Promise` returned from `loadDiscoveryDocument()` is subscribed to, but the `auth.guard` redirects me back to the login page, losing the `id_token` and such from the url before I can let the `OAuthService` collect it for me and store it in storage.

### My Question

Is there a way to get this to work without having to change the routing structure of my application?  I have no need for a "`HomeComponent`" that acts as a "`LoginComponent`" as well as a "`HomeComponent`" depending on the signed-in state.

Comment: Hello Jake. If you move `this.oauthService.tryLogin({});` from being in the constructor to be in an `ngOnInit()` method (and implement `OnInit` on your class), does it help?

Comment: Matt, it does not help because it is the auth guard that is redirecting me to the login component before the promise is resolved and tryLogin is invoked. The only thing I can think of is to create a callback component, have okta redirect to that, persist my tokens, and then use the angular router service to redirect to root. I was just hoping there was a cleaner solution. In theory, though, a callback component to sit at while my identity is set would work, yea?

Comment: I just realized that it probably would have helped to show that the projects module is where the project routing is defined and that /projects is guarded against by `auth.guard`

Comment: Can you use Okta's Auth SDK instead? This allows you to create your own login form instead of redirecting. This is covered in the same blog post you referenced. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/04/17/angular-authentication-with-oidc#authentication-with-the-okta-auth-sdk

Comment: I'll give that a shot.  That was what I was going to move to next anyway.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I think I've got this working, but I'm having trouble keeping the Angular OAuthService and the OktaAuth object.  Which one should I be using to grab information about the user's profile from?  If I use the service, I get errors about not having access tokens.  I'm not sure I'm looking at the right documentation...

Comment: It looks like your new blog post [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/06/13/add-authentication-angular-pwa) answers my question

Comment: I'd like to ask you more questions, but I don't know what the most appropriate way to do would be...I'm trying to work though the sdk and Angular.  It looks like anytime I want to use the `OAuthService`, I need to make sure that `loadDiscoveryDocument` has run and finished running.  Problem is, different components need different things: My profile component wants to load the user profile.  It works if I navigate to the profile page from somewhere else.  But if I start at the profile page or reload the app so profile component is first you see, the discovery document hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: Do I need to wrap everything with a discovery document load promise first?  Or is there a way this would work best with Angular and how things get loaded in?

Comment: @MattRaible, if and when you have a moment, could you comment on my answer below?  I would like to know if this is an acceptable approach from your perspective and would love some feedback.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I was unable to get the login button with redirect to work with the way my application's routing is organized.  But using the JavaScript SDK, I had a little more flexibility and thanks to @MattRaible's frequent blog posts on the Okta developer pages, I was able to come up with something that worked well for me.  It took a lot of debugging the sdk to figure out the order of operations that would get me what I want, so hope this helps someone out there:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc/dist';

declare let OktaAuth: any;

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  discoveryDocumentLoaded: boolean;

  constructor(
    private oauthService: OAuthService,
    private router: Router) { }

  init() {
    this.oauthService.redirectUri = window.location.origin;
    this.oauthService.clientId = '<client-id>';
    this.oauthService.scope = 'openid profile email';
    this.oauthService.oidc = true;
    this.oauthService.issuer = '<preview-path>';
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument()
      .then(() => {
        this.discoveryDocumentLoaded = true;
        this.oauthService.tryLogin({});
      });
  }

  logOut() {
    this.oauthService.logOut();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  loginWithPassword(username: string, password: string) {
    this.oauthService.createAndSaveNonce().then(nonce => {
      const authClient = new OktaAuth({
        url: '<preview-path>'
      });
      authClient.signIn({
        username: username,
        password: password
      })
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status === 'SUCCESS') {
            authClient.token.getWithoutPrompt({
              clientId: '<client-id>',
              responseType: ['id_token', 'token'],
              scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
              sessionToken: response.sessionToken,
              nonce: nonce,
              redirectUri: window.location.origin
            })
              .then(tokens => {
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', tokens[1].accessToken);
                this.oauthService.processIdToken(tokens[0].idToken, tokens[1].accessToken);
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
              })
              .catch(console.error);
          } else {
            throw new Error('We cannot handle the ' + response.status + ' status');
          }
        })
        .fail(console.error);
    });
  }

  loadUserProfile() {
    const returnFunc = () => this.oauthService.loadUserProfile()
      .catch(console.log);

    if (this.discoveryDocumentLoaded) {
      return returnFunc();
    } else {
      return this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument()
        .then(returnFunc);
    }
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.oauthService.hasValidIdToken() && this.oauthService.getIdentityClaims()
  }

}
```

Here is how I use the service in my application:

#### `app.component.ts`

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    constructor(
        ...
        private _auth: AuthenticationService) {
        ...
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._auth.init();
    }
    ...
}
```

#### `profile.component.ts`

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { OktaProfile } from 'app/okta-profile';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'app/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.scss']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  profile: OktaProfile;

  constructor(private _auth: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._auth.loadUserProfile()
      .then(oktaProfile => this.profile = <OktaProfile>oktaProfile);
  }

}
```

Comment: A couple of things I see in your code: `import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc/dist';` should be `import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';` Also, how is `init()` called? If it was `ngOnInit` and you implemented `OnInit`, I'd understand, but I don't with this setup. Of course, the most important thing is that you got it to work. Nice job!

Comment: Ah okay, I'll remove `/dist'` from the end.  `init()` is being called in a component's `OnInit` handler.  I was worried about this too because this is a service, so one would have to know to call this method in the `ngOnInit` method ahead of time.  But I think that practice is well known at this point with things that are making calls out to external services.  I just showed the service and not the components using it.  But I'll add that to my answer above...

Comment: I have same problem with my ionic app, This solution is not working for me . Please help, this problem is posted here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831398/okta-session-get-cleared-after-opening-web-app-in-new-tab)